# Spring WS Configuration Wsdl11DestinationProvider Error

Tags: ssl, wsdl, spring-ws

The error is happening when trying to define the wsdl endpoint. The stacktrace is stating that it doesn't exist, however, I can navigate to the url. It is https, and I have the cert stored in my cacerts + root keystore?? Help??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

<!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />
<bean id="abstractClient" abstract="true">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
    <property name="destinationProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.client.support.destination.Wsdl11DestinationProvider">
            <property name="wsdl" value="https://ws.firstdataglobalgateway.com:443/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider" class="com.intellavia.provider.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xmlbeans.XmlBeansMarshaller" />
<bean id="httpClientParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams">
    <property name="authenticationPreemptive" value="true" />
    <property name="connectionManagerClass" value="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientParams" />
</bean>
<bean id="credentials" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
    <constructor-arg value="*********" />
    <constructor-arg value="*********" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"></constructor-arg>
    <property name="credentials" ref="credentials" />
</bean>
<bean id="fdggwsapiorder" parent="abstractClient" class="com.api.client.order">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="messageSender" ref="messageSender" />
</bean>
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.client.support.destination.Wsdl11DestinationProvider#7424ce' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'wsdl' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL [https://ws.firstdataglobalgateway.com:443/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl] does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:219)
    ... 26 more

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Try to download the wsld to your local and point to it.

Comment: @jddsantaella Thanks for the response, yea I have tried that. I actually have it on my server, then I switch the WSDL url at runtime. The problem is I need to post to that url.

Comment: So, does it work if you have it on a local server? Are you under behind a proxy?

Comment: @jddsantaella No proxy, local server it works. I have a test application just for testing the wsdl, works. Implementing it into the regular application doesn't. Both running on same server instance.

Answer (score 0):

The server I was trying to retrieve the wsdl from was expecting a key and password combination . The JVM also required that the SSL cert be stored in the cacerts file as a trusted entity. I was setting the keystore property programmatically, however this request was being processed before the switch.